# Why does the this popup think it is encountering the edge of the screen?

Tags: c#, wpf, popup

The [Popup Placement Behavior Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/popup-placement-behavior) shows how to position a popup using several properties:

- Placement
- PlacementTarget
- PlacmentRectangle
- VerticalOffset/HorizontalOffset

Using these, we can set the *target area*, *target origin*, and *placement alignment point*. The guide goes on to describe a whole host of conditions for how the popup is placed in the event that it encounters the screen.

In my application, I created a popup programmatically as a response to user input and set the properties:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Popup popup = new Popup();
    popup.Child = new PopupContent();
    popup.Placement = PlacementMode.Right;
    popup.PlacementTarget = redRectangle;

    popup.StaysOpen = false;
    popup.IsOpen = true;
}
```

The intended behavior was that the popup would appear on the right of rectangle. Instead I got this:

[image: Incorrect Popup Placement]

#### Why does the popup's placement alignment point change to the left side of the rectangle as if it has encountered the edge of the screen?

---

MVCE Resources:

```
<Window x:Class="PopupTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Width="700" Height="700">
    <Grid>
        <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Create Popup" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="83" Height="25"/>
        <Rectangle x:Name="redRectangle" Width="20" Height="20" Fill="Red"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```
<UserControl x:Class="PopupTest.PopupContent"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         Width="300" Height="300">
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2">
        <Border BorderBrush="#FF50A0E0" BorderThickness="10" Background="White">
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Padding="10">
                <Label Content="Popup!" FontSize="70" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
            </Border>
        </Border>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: There's not enough room on the right side of that rectangle for the entire dialog to fit on the screen, unless you haven't shown us the whole screen.

Comment: You'd think that might be the case; however if you resize the window it still is placed to the left.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. Which version on the .NET Framework and Windows are you on

Comment: Hi @mm8, I'm using .NET 4.6.1. One thing I did notice was that there needs to be enough room to display the popup on the left, otherwise the popup is coerced to the right.

Comment: I have .NET 4.7.1 installed and running your code the Popup is always displayed to the right of the rectangle as expected.

Comment: I just learned that Windows 10 has tablet PC settings, my code seems to be adhering to them despite not being a tablet device. Changing my settings to be left-handed flipped the popup according to my expectations. How is your PC configured?
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/context-menu-going-left-not-right/a09e42df-fdd0-45fc-a501-7e5e145a22b3